# My wordpress site doesn't render correctly on larger monitors

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been working on  [this site](http://shawati.ae/) for the last couple of days. Everything was going perfectly well on my 13" laptop - and even on the 17" PC laptop I checked it on. However, the magazine owners looked at it on a 21" screen earlier today and apparently it looks radically different. I just checked it on a monitor in an Internet cafe, and it appears they have a point. Can anyone help?

Comment: Better provide a screenshot how it have to look on small resolution.

Answer (score 0):

In the style sheet, replace

```
body { color:#000; background:url(images/bg.jpg) fixed; }
```

with

```
body { color:#000; background:url(images/bg.jpg) fixed no-repeat center; }
```

Then, center the content with

```
body {width: 600px; /* from the background image */ margin: 0 auto; }
```

this should work better.